# How i can debug Facebook Instant Articles integration via test application(without moderation)?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-instant-articles

I need develop Facebook Instant Articles Integration for self-written CMS(written with php 5.6 using Facebook php SDK).
It will be posting articles automatically when publish on site by editor;
I am created a test application and test page for posting ans pass their APP_ID, APP_SECRET, PAGE_ID to api method arguments.
When I tried push to FB some example article, i got an error:

```
Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException] exception 
'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message 
'(#200) Requires pages_manage_instant_articles permission to manage the object'
```

How i can debug my integration(with publishing articles into some sandbox and watching them in Facebook admin panel) without checking my application and page?

Comment: You'll need to get an access token with the `pages_manage_instant_articles` permission. As an admin on the app, you can do this without that permission having to have been reviewed by Facebook. Easiest way is via the "Get Token" button on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: Thank`s! @ceejayoz